# display data from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am beginner in php and mysql, php where I make an HTML table display name hour date and show me the table of my database containing the fields "name" "hour" "date"
The name of the database is androidhive and the table name is products

My code is:

```
<?php
include("connectbd.php"); //importamos el archivo para la coneccion a la base de datos

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products",$link); //Hacemos la consulta
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
echo"<table><tr><td>Nombre</td><td>hora<td>fecha</td></tr>" //Hacemos una tabla html para ordenar los datos

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ //Guardaremos los datos en un array llamado $row cada indice del array sera el nombre del campo "Nombre","Apellidos", "Email", "Id"
echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]."".$row["fecha"]</td>"; //le pasamos el id a la pagina del link para que reconosca el dato
}
echo"</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the error is SCREAM:

> Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\droidlogin\citas.php on line 13

Comment: USE myqli family or PDO, Mysql family is depriciated

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If you're just beginning PHP, the you shouldn't be using the MySQL library, but take the advice given by others and learn mySQLi or PDO right from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]."".$row["fecha"]</td>"; //le pasamos el id a la pagina del link para que reconosca el dato
```

To

```
echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]."".$row["fecha"]."</td>"; //le pasamos el id a la pagina del link para que reconosca el dato
```

Missing `."` after `$row["fecha"]`

Comment: thanks!! but now the error is  SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp\www\droidlogin\citas.php on line 5
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0018 254568 {main}( ) ..\citas.php:0

Comment: @user2056944 does `$link` is defined inside `connectbd.php`?

Comment: i correct the error now just this

  SCREAM: Error ignored for suppression
(!) Warning: mysql_fetch_array () Expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean Given in C: \ wamp \ www \ droidlogin \ citas.php on line 13

Comment: @user2056944 , i m not sure but remove $link from select query and then try.

Comment: replace include("connectbd.php"); to require_once "connectbd.php";

Comment: can you share your database connection file ? its error come for database connection.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
echo"<table><tr><td>Nombre</td><td>hora<td>fecha</td></tr>"
```

Need a `;` at the end:

```
echo"<table><tr><td>Nombre</td><td>hora<td>fecha</td></tr>";
```

And this one:

```
echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]."".$row["fecha"]</td>";
```

has an *unclosed attachement*, mean one `."`left:

```
echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]."".$row["fecha"]."</td>";
```

Comment: thanks! now the error is SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\wamp\www\droidlogin\citas.php on line 14

Comment: @user2056944 did you made both modification?

Comment: yes the error now is  ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\droidlogin\citas.php on line 13
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 254864 {main}( ) ..\citas.php:0
2 1.0130 270096 mysql_fetch_array ( ) ..\citas.php:13

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 echo"<td>".$row["Nombre"]." ".$row["hora"]." ".$row["fecha"]."</td>";
```